# How I can delete `id` and `sub id`

Tags: mysql, database

I have database like this:

| id | name_categories | id_categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | General | 0 |
| 2 | hotnews | 1 |
| 3 | breakingnews | 2 |

The main categories are:

- (`General`) with `id = 1` and `id_categories = 0`
- Sub categories for main (`hostnews`)  `id_categories = 1`
- (`breakingnews`) is sub main for (`hotnews`) with `id_categories = 2`
- `id` linked with `id_categories`

Deleting `general` should delete all `id_categories` linked with:

- `id` `main`
- `sub main`
- `sub sub main`
  How can this be done with PDO PHP?

Comment: you can also do it with foreign keys.

Comment: Is this the maximum depth it can be or is infinite?

Comment: Try using self referencing foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct database design covers this type of tasks automatically:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_categories` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_categories` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_categories` (`id_categories`),
  CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categories`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Whenever you delete a row from this table, mysql will also delete all the referencing rows, and rows that reference referencing rows, etc.

You can recursively delete rows with PHP, but this is a bad idea for a number of reasons.